# How to find key from HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                       Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
                        while( keys.hasNext() ){
                             key = (String)keys.next();
                           item = json.getString(key);
                           mList.add(item);
                           ItemsHashMap.hmstock.put(key, item);
```

Please can any one tell me how to find key from this code example like{17=Common English,16=Basic english}.i want get onliy key means (17)from this please help me...because these all 18 items show in listview

Comment: `HashMap.keySet()`. Read example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_keyset.htm

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar-I want get only one key which i selected from ListView.

Comment: @PankajKumar You cannot get the key for a value. Key should be value and value key. Or you want a two-way Map.

Comment: @m0skit0 I didn't ask this question. And I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: @PankajKumar You mean you have "Common English" and you want to get 17 back, am I right?

Comment: @ m0skit0 abstly right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try by**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
         position,
         long id) {

         String name = mList.get(position);
         Iterator itr = ItemsHashMap.hmstock.keySet().iterator();
         while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String key2 = (String) itr.next();
                if (ItemsHashMap.hmstock.get(key2).toString().equals(name) {
                    keyId = Integer.parseInt(key2);// parsing to int because i am assuming KeyId variable is of int 
                    break;
                }
            }
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + keyId,
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // keyId Shows the null Value
         }
```

Comment: i m putting my all code excluding adapter class please tell me how i get the value i m puttion my api also http://twominenglish.com/api/getcategories?page=1 just help me its urgent for me

Comment: where you want to get the value ? i mean from hashmap ect ?

Comment: @farha see my updated answer and also update your question with code you provided me !

Comment: its working wrong through this code it gets the position in listview but i want the position according to api example {17=common english}but in list view it is shown in 3rd position its gave 3 not 17 pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

1)Change

```
ItemsHashMap.hmstock.put(key, item);
```

to

```
ItemsHashMap.hmstock.put(item, key);
```

2)so now u are actually displaying item where in hashmap it will be stored as "key".so whenever u click on listview u get selected text as item..so item became key of your map.

key=Entertainment English;
value=1;

3)now pass your item to get its value;

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(item))//here item is key;item=Entertainment English
  {

         String value=hashMap.get(item);
//so it will return value of this key
//value="1";
   }
```

Comment: -i cant understant your code...pls tell me more about this..new in this field.

Comment: what is in your listview?

Comment: i mean when u select on your listview then what u get any key or value?

Comment: when i clicked on list view i get the value means "Common English" not get the key means 17 that is the prblm..

Comment: as u r displaying 18 items and your hashmap contains 18 fields..also u said above that your keys are in "0","1"...to"17" format.right?

Comment: no, in my hashmap 17 itme and i want get key from 1 to 17 just see mah api http://twominenglish.com/api/getcategories?page=1

Comment: check my edited answer.it works if u use any simple listview which contains only your 18 values.

Comment: @geet-i think u can't understand what i want..i explain u this is my api twominenglish.com/api/getcategories?page=1 {"17" : "cOMMON ENGLISH"} i want that id when i select on listview but through your code if this COMMON ENGLISH is in 3 position it return me 3 but i want its return me 17....pls help me

Comment: i editing my hole on code pls see and where i put the code for this

Comment: check hashMap.containsKey(item)

Comment: its exists but it can't retrun key of that item that is the prblm can i show the my hole code to u

Comment: i m editing my code plsease see this code hashmap class in other package i just show u through the comment

Comment: @tarem give me the write code and its working correctly what i want

Comment: ok..Do u get item="selected Text of listview" in your onitemselected listener?

Comment: debug your hashmap in itemselectedlistener as well as "item",if exists then debug also   value=hashMap.get(item); & declare String value as global;

Comment: i have done though iterator.its give me fine and correct reuslt but thanks a lot for your reply